# Checking out a git branch always removes/"deletes" files in repo

Tags: git

Strange issue with git I've never run into before. Members of our team have noticed when checking out a particular git branch from our repo, a few JS files will be "deleted" from the repo/tracked as removed. For instance:

1. I'm on Branch_A. It is in a completely clean state, and the repo contains files `1.js`, `2.js`, and `3.js`.
2. I check out Branch_B (the trouble branch) but make no changes. Immediately if I run `git status` I see:

```
    deleted:    1.js
    deleted:    2.js
    deleted:    3.js
```

3. I 're-add' those files by checking them back in from origin/Branch_A:

```
git checkout origin/Branch_A 1.js 2.js 3.js
```

`git status` now shows I have nothing to commit.

4. I check out/switch back to Branch_A. I make no changes.
5. I check out Branch_B again. Running `git status` shows that once again the files are missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do the files appear when you check them out? Have you tried `git add`?

Comment: sounds like your `origin` is not the same as `local` with `Branch_A`

Comment: @Michael, `origin/Branch_A` is the same as `local/Branch_A`. It doesn't matter whether I check out the files from local or remote. :( @isherwood the files do appear in `Branch_B` when I check them back out from `Branch_A`. Once I do that, `git add` doesn't do anything because they are already checked in to the `Branch_B` branch; they just get deleted during the switch in branches. (What this results in is team members inadvertently removing them from our remote when they check in other changes).

Comment: Question: in the `git status` output, are these deleted files "staged for commit" or "not staged for commit"?  (Either way this should not happen but the difference tells us more about the bug.)

Comment: @torek, they are shown as "not staged for commit" when initially switching to Branch_B and running `git status`. After re-adding the files with `git checkout` from Branch_A, I have the usual "nothing to commit, working branch clean."

Comment: OK, that's interesting: it means the problem is strictly in your working tree, and not in Git's index. These files are all named *numerically?* (If they were named alphabetically, I'd suspect uppercase vs lowercase issues on WIndows or macOS next.)

Comment: @torek,gotcha! This solved it, and now I feel a bit dumb. They are named alphabetically (just used numerals in the example) and camelcased e.g. fileName.js. However looks like in Branch_A they were somehow switched to non-camelcased file names, while Branch_B had the old file names and the "replacement" renamed files were not carried over. Weirdly, referents to the file elsewhere in our code did not seem to cause issues despite the renaming, so I missed the possibility. Thank you!

Comment: Aha. This is why a [mre] is useful: sometimes in an attempt to summarize a problem, we remove something important :-)